# Android: layout_gravity center does not center

Tags: android, android-layout, layout-gravity

I have a problem, that is maybe silly, but I just can't figure out why this is not working.

Basically, I have a header in my activity. This header should be centered.

Layout-XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView 
    style="@style/TextHeader"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/define"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Definition in styles.xml

```
<style name="TextHeader">
    <item name="android:textSize">20dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">15dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">15dp</item>
</style>
```

As I understand, `layout_gravity` defines the gravity of the component itself, while `gravity` defines the gravity of the content of this component. I tried both ways, both with `center` and center_horizontal. I also made the header TextView `layout_width:wrap_content` and tried to center it with `layout_gravity`, but the result is always following (same thing if I put the app on my phone)

[image]

why is this so? how can I fix it?

Comment: haven't you tried center_vertical? You could also use relativelayout instead of linear layout.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a few different solutions, this is one:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/define" />
```

This is another:

```
<RelativeLayout .../>

    <TextView
        ...
        android:centerInParent="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

You can adjust your style properties to whichever method you choose.

Comment: I guess it works only when the width is set to match_parent or fill_parent

Comment: Your second solution is not correct, the attribute is called `layout_centerInParent`

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
```

android:gravity - centers all views in **parent** (use it in layout)

android:layout_gravity - centers your **view** in parent (use it inside all views you want to center)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `"center_horizontal"` and `layout_width:"fill_parent"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 center_vertical
```

or

```
 Use Relative Layout.
```